# Question about rounding answers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

What is 3.625612m to the nearest mm? Don't the first two decimal places reprsent centimetres and the next 3 millimetres so the answer is 3.625612?

Comment: No, because there are only $10$ (and not $1000$) millimeters in one centimeter, so the answer is $3.625$ (in other words, there are $1000$ millimeters in one **meter**). If you want the **nearest** mm, then you should round the result to $3.626$.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion the $.$ dot is in some places used as decimal comma, while in other places it is used to 'separate thousands', so in this case it would be usefull to write the units to the numbers=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0.01m = 1cm$ and $0.001m = 1mm$ therefore $3.625612m = 3625.612mm$ which is conventionally rounded to $3626mm$.